# Using variable for a method name

Tags: php, variables

I would like the variable `$column` to be a part of my method name.

```
$column = ucfirst($column);
```

I tried it like this but that doesn't work:

```
$query->get{$column}();
```

So let's say the value of `$column` is `Email`, I want the method to be called like this:

```
$query->getEmail();
```

How would that be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix get should be part of the variable.
Try something like :

```
$methodName = 'get' . ucfirst($column);
$query->$methodName();
```